# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSupported' of undefined angular serve:ssr

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, server-side-rendering

Just before this issue I had fixed `app.firestore of undefined` by adding

```
           "externalDependencies": [
              "@firebase/app",
              "@firebase/firestore"
            ],
```

inside `angular.json` `server->options`.

But right after fixing that issue now I came up with

`RROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSupported' of undefined`

I tried to search in my project directory with that keyword and found that it is depend upon `firebase.messaging.isSupported()` where these two imports are made in same file.

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-messaging.js");
```

I am quite not sure which dependencies I need to import to fixed this issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

`angular.json`

```
"server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {  
            "outputPath": "dist/treo/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "optimization": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/@treo/styles"
              ]
            },
            "externalDependencies": [
              "@firebase/app",
              "@firebase/firestore"
            ],
            "extractLicenses": false
          },
```

Answer (score 1):

In `firebase.service.ts` file I wrap the `firebase.messaging.isSupported()` inside the `isPlatformBrowser` to detect if its loaded in the browser. With the below change
its working fine for now.

```
private messaging = firebase.messaging.isSupported() ?  firebase.messaging() : null;
```

```
private messaging = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId) ?( firebase.messaging.isSupported() ?  firebase.messaging() : null) :null;
```